# XSD - cvc-elt.4.2: Cannot resolve ''{1}'' to a type definition for element ''{0}''

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to validate xml file against my xsd schema.

XSD schema:

```
   <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
               xmlns:myType="http://iso.org/my/type/myType"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
               targetNamespace="http://iso.org/my/type/myType"
               elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0.0">
...
<xsd:complexType name="MyComplexType">
    ....
</xsd:complexType>
```

XML file:

```
<otx xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:myType="http://iso.org/my/type/myType"
     xmlns="http://iso.org/my/type" id="someId" name="someName" package="somePackage" timestamp="....." version="1.0.0">
....
<realisation xsi:type="dataType:MyComplexType">
   <dataType:elements>
       ...
   </dataType:elements>
</realisation>
```

But I always receive `Cannot resolve 'dataType:MyComplextType' to a type definition for element 'realisation'.`

Files should be in correct directory, does someone has any idea, what's wrong? Or what might be wrong?

Comment: What is the declared type for element 'realisation' in the XSD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace prefix dataType hasn't been declared. Try

```
xsi:type="myType:MyComplexType"
```